# Assigning object data to a typescript interface throws error

Tags: typescript, interface

im currently facing an issue when i try to assign values to interface properties. 
I'm getting this error: `"Variable 'info' is used before being assigned."`

My code looks like this:

```
export interface Info {
        name: ProductName;
        price: number;
        labels?: string[];
}

export interface ProductName {
    key: string;
}

let responseData = 
{ name: "dummy",price: 123, labels: ["red", "small"]};

let info: Info;
info.name = {"key": responseData.name};
info.price = responseData.price;
info.labels = responseData.labels;
console.log(info);
```

Would be great if someone can help me with this issue :)

Comment: Do you know why `let x; x.y = 0;` would throw a runtime error in JavaScript?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `info`. (`let info: Info = {};`)

Answer (score 0):

When TypeScript is transpiled into TypeScript, its type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure); all type annotations, assertions, and declarations are stripped from the code. TypeScript's compiler does not turn `let info: Info;` into any kind of initialization JavaScript; it just strips off the `: Info` part.  That means your code will become something like:

```
let info;
info.name = {"key": responseData.name};
```

That will be a runtime error, because `info` will be `undefined` when you try to add a property to it. You need to initialize `info` in TypeScript, just like in JavaScript.

---

You can't write `let info: Info = {}` because the compiler will (rightfully) complain that an empty object is not an `Info`.  The easiest way to proceed is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that the empty object you're initializing to will *eventually* be a valid `Info`:

```
let info = {} as Info;
```

This is not very type safe, since if you forget to initialize all the properties, the compiler won't warn you:

```
let info = {} as Info;
//info.name = { "key": responseData.name }; <-- oops forgot this
info.name.key.toUpperCase(); // runtime error but no compiler error
```

So type assertions are best avoided if you can refactor into something verifiably type safe; for example, a better approach is to initialize `info` as a valid `Info` right from the start:

```
let info: Info = {
    name: { "key": responseData.name },
    price: responseData.price,
    labels: responseData.labels
}
console.log(info);
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSSXQjgG8BYAKDhriUwFtgAuOABSggBMBXbGAHKNgAbiq04YKAlyskPBgCM0Y6rQA2mZeoDOAflY6Y0pAHMA2gF1VAXypVQkWIhRosudp178hTMnHFaAGtgAE9DY2RTW3tKdWB4KGAdSCQdYAARTBhMOABeQJpSOmFWACJeBgZQsoAaSWlZOABGACYAZnrNbR1WczKkrjq4Mp0GTHV1Mss4G1UqeiYUnDwAQR105wo1Gnj4ZGJ8shs4TB0CIghVCQB6G4OIADpFvDz-MpCa1iSUiDTM7KYZ7CWYiOAAHgAtJC4BAIGBzsQoKYIPAYAALBA6QouYjApiPT6PGAQACqYDAaAAwmdgAAKACUYLucCgPBQCD8aE4UAAhDiHo8pDJXqzkql0lkckLGqIBZdHt1gLojj8JQDpUrdNdaNg-joIPFFRBTHSHkzYnZKAthMsPIQEPBthI9riIKxCIc3s6JLQXqxih8wmVvuL9RqgS9ZrUcRJhU01eGpUD48AYztfVremLfv9k4qtMrsRmrRI9WlDcBjabzbYgA)